# Apache Flink FileSource Directory

Tags: java, apache-flink

I've been trying to read in some files from a directory with Apache Flink. However, it's important that I am able to know or control the order in which they're read in. Is there any way to do that with Flink, or does it have its own method of determining what order to read them in?

I have been googling all over the internet, and haven't found a solid answer for how to make sure that FileSource or FileEnumerator read them in in the order that I want. The most recent question about this was in 2018, and I'm just wondering if there have been any improvements, or if I still have to make my own function to do it.